# How can I extract the words between two strings in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed

I want to extract the text between 2 strings in Shellscript.
From the below string, I want to extract the text between Summary: and Arrived at.
`mySTring="Summary: New Arrival Arrived At:11/8/2018, 01:38:00 P.M."`
How can this be done?

Comment: Devjith, if any of the existing answers solved your problem, let them know by clicking the checkmark next to their answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Strictly following the requirements, assuming the text was already in a variable, you would do:

```
s="Summary: New Arrival Arrived At:11/8/2018, 01:38:00 P.M."
s="${s#*Summary:}"
s="${s%% Arrived At*}"
printf '%s\n' "$s"
```

... but if your data always has a space after `Summary:` then you may want to strip that off as well:

```
s="${s#*Summary: }"
s="${s%%Arrived At*}"
```

... ditto with the leading space before `Arrived At`:

```
s="${s#*Summary: }"
s="${s%% Arrived At*}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Same can be achieve with grep & Perl Regex.

```
$ echo "$mySTring" | grep -Po  "Summary: \K(.*)(?= Arrived )"
New Arrival
```

> \K: grep will keep everything before \K in matching the pattern but
>   while printing, it will be excluded.
>
> ?= is a positive lookahead  Captured part must be followed by this
>   part in parentheses to get captured but in the end output it will not
>   printed or extracted.

Comment: Note that this only works with GNU Grep, not with the BSD grep that is available in MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mySTring="Summary: New Arrival Arrived At:11/8/2018, 01:38:00 P.M."

$ echo ${mySTring}
Summary: New Arrival Arrived At:11/8/2018, 01:38:00 P.M.

$ echo ${mySTring} | sed "s/.*Summary://;s/Arrived.*//"
 New Arrival
```

if you want to do it only using bash, then try this..

```
mySTring="Summary: New Arrival Arrived At:11/8/2018, 01:38:00 P.M."
mySTring=${mySTring#*:}
$ echo ${mySTring}
New Arrival Arrived At:11/8/2018, 01:38:00 P.M.
$ echo ${mySTring%%Arrived*}
New Arrival
$ mySTring=${mySTring%%Arrived*}
$ echo ${mySTring}
New Arrival
```

String manipulation in bash - https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Thank you..its working...i tried with sed but the syntax was incorrect.